# React - rendering with moment.js

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I am trying to render this:

```
<p>Some date: {moment('12-25-1995', 'MM-DD-YYYY')}</p>
```

and getting error

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Mon Dec 25 1995 00:00:00 GMT+0100). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `MeetingComponent`.
```

I see this is a common React response when trying to output objects.

What would be the best practice solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Moment's `format` function to return a string, otherwise you're trying to render a Moment Object!

```
<p>Some date: {moment('12-25-1995', 'MM-DD-YYYY').format('MM/DD/YYYY')}</p>
```

Let me explain this more thoroughly: the `moment` constructor can handle two parameters, the first being the date and the second being the format of the date passed as the first parameter. This has nothing to do with rendering the date, it just allows MomentJS to create a correct representation of your date, and the second parameter can be omitted when using the standard YYYY-MM-DD format.

Once you have a Moment Object, you can do some neat things with it, such as adding days, diffing two dates, format a date in any format, etc...

If you already have the date in your desired format, you don't need to use Moment to print it - you already have the correct string. But you can use moment change the format of your date and print it in some other:

```
<p>Some date: {moment('12-25-1995', 'MM-DD-YYYY').format('YYYY/MM/DD')}</p>
```

Comment: Good answer, but worth noting that there are actually several overloads to the moment constructor, notably strict mode and locale in addition to what you have mentioned here. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/